# When the verticle will undeploy in vertx

Tags: vert.x

I am seeing the below statement in vertx document and I want to understand is the verticle is automatically undeploy when process completed or we need to explicitly call the undeploy method.

Automatic clean-up in verticles
If you’re creating consumers and producer from inside verticles, those consumers and producers will be automatically closed when the verticle is undeployed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This statement indicates that when a verticle is undeployed, Vert.x resources like event bus consumers, event bus producers or HTTP servers will be closed automatically.

As for when verticles are undeployed, they are if you do it manually or if you started them via the Vert.x command line or the Launcher class.

Comment: I have started my verticle and the server is running continuously and process the events. When it will undeploy my verticle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. What I meant is that when you send a SIGTERM signal to the process, verticles will be undeployed. Is that what you asked?